# Arithmetic overflow error converting to data type datetime

Tags: t-sql, date, expression, ssms-2012

I am having issues with the formula below. The goal is to project a future date based on (CEIDAvgUsage-Usage/Burnrate). I have been searching for an answer for quite sometime and can find anything helpful. Either the expression im using is wrong or something else. Does anyone have suggestions.

```
RIGHT (CONVERT (varchar, CASE WHEN (GetDate() + (CEIDAvgUsage - Usage) / BurnRate) < GetDate() THEN GetDate() 
ELSE (Getdate() + (CEIDAvgUsage - Usage) / BurnRate) 
END, 103), 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it doing wrong? And what exactly do you want it to do? Here's an example of something that may work:

```
DECLARE @CEIDAvgUsage   INT = 40
    , @Usage INT = 20
    , @BurnRate INT = 2

SELECT CAST(DATEADD (dd,CASE WHEN (@CEIDAvgUsage - @Usage) / @BurnRate <= 0
THEN 0 ELSE (@CEIDAvgUsage - @Usage) / @BurnRate END,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that it is trying to convert this

```
(CEIDAvgUsage - Usage) / BurnRate)
```

to a date

this just makes no sense

```
(GetDate() + (CEIDAvgUsage - Usage) / BurnRate) < GetDate()
```

you are adding a number to a date  and you have GetDate() on both sides

```
(CEIDAvgUsage - Usage) / BurnRate < 0
```

if BurnRate is positive

```
CEIDAvgUsage < Usage

RIGHT ( CONVERT (varchar, CASE WHEN CEIDAvgUsage < Usage THEN GetDate() 
                               ELSE DateAdd(dd, Getdate(), (CEIDAvgUsage - Usage) / BurnRate) 
                          END
                , 103)
      , 7)
```